# Is mev-geth analougue to geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes, flashbots, mev

I was reading about ethereum node impementations and found something about [mev-geth](https://github.com/flashbots/mev-geth), wich is a fork of geth made by [flashbots](https://www.flashbots.net/).

If i want run a node just to propagate my own transactions and query the chain, are interchangeable geth and mev-geth? Or mev-geth have particular implications?

Comment: subscribe to Flashbot's discord group , it is better place to get an answer about this topic

Comment: tried already, nobody answered my question, then i'm trying here

Answer (score 1):

Geth and mev-geth are both Ethereum node implementations, but mev-geth is a fork of Geth created by Flashbots with additional functionality for detecting and mitigating frontrunning, a type of attack on the Ethereum network.

If you are only planning to use your node for propagating your own transactions and querying the blockchain, you can use either Geth or mev-geth. However, if you are concerned about frontrunning and want to use the additional features provided by mev-geth to detect and mitigate this type of attack, then you should use mev-geth.

Answer (score 0):

We released the 1.13.14 version on github, it's a mix of flashbots implementation and the latest (as of deneb update) geth version

https://github.com/NaliFinance/mev-geth

So you have the standard geth version. plus the two RPC endpoints to simulate bundles